# Didn't get ads after i updated the sdk

Tags: android, admob

I was using admob for more than a year but since i updated the sdk i can't get ads.So,i guest that i may have done something wrong..
i downloaded the new sdk,added to my app and then just placed the following code into my xml file

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14d3813d4df3d5d" />
```

and this code in my activity:

```
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
                adRequest.setTesting(true);
                 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Where is my wrong?May i do something more?Thanks a lot,i have waisted many hours to solve it..:)

Comment: have you looked in logCat console output? It should contain some logs from admob about what's wrong (I guess it's configuration in AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: i m not getting anything wrong in the logcat,that's my problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're trying to make the adview live by itself in the entire layout. That's not the recommended way to do it. You should put it in something like a relativelayout and try putting

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```

Not sure if it will help enough though.